# Error starting MySQL server through commandline on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, command-line, mysql

I am installing MySQL manually on my Mac and during that I started MySQL through command line using this command

```
    $ /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
      Starting MySQL
    . ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Flipkart-   MacBookPro.local.pid).
```

I must mention that first I had started and after that I had shutdown the MySQL using

```
 /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

And after this when I again tried to start it did n't came up.

No idea what is causing this? And how to fix these kinds of error?

Answer (score 0):

use the following command instead, it's a permissions issue

```
sudo ./mysql.server start
```